# Playing a video in full screen after startup

Tags: automation, startup-applications, fullscreen

I need a way to run an info screen. I have a video file that it's supposed to play, how could I automate ubuntu to open the file in for example VLC and play in full screen? I'll probably use auto-on and off in BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

- Search for **Startup Applications** in dash and open it.
- Open the **Startup Applications** and click **Add**
- Fill the fields as follows replacing `<my_username>` by your username and the following path by the video path where `<the_video.mp4>` is the video:

  - Name:    `Open my awesome video`
  - Command: `vlc -L -f <video_path>`
  - Comment: `You can leave me blank`

---

1. `vlc`: yes, you guessed it! it's the command.
2. `-L`: Plays the video infinitely (when it ends, then starts again).
3. `-f`: Puts in fullscreen automatically.
4. `<video_path>`: The absolute path of the video. A valid path is this:

   ```
   /home/johndoe/Desktop/my_awesome_movie.mp4
   ```

   Where `johndoe` is the user.